# Is Purim Panim Chadashot for reciting Sheva berachot

Tags: halacha, purim, wedding, sheva-brachos, even-haezer

Inspired by [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/25776/33665) question, I am curious, is Purim considered  by  Halacha to be Panim Chadashot? Or no, is Purim not considered similar to Shabbat and Yom Tov in this respect and having new physical guests present is  required for reciting Sheva Berachot?

Comment: Well those who hold its taloi in neshema yiseira for sure hold that theres no panim chadashos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[R' Shlomo Algazi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solomon_Nissim_Algazi) (1610-1683) in his sefer *[Gufei Halachos](https://hebrewbooks.org/44519)* wrote that on Purim one does not require *panim chadashos*, just like Shabbos and Yom Tov (EH 62:8). He explained his ruling based on Tosfos' explanation (Kesuvos 7b) why Shabbos and Yom Tov don't require *panim chadashos* - because it is customary to add to the joy and festive *seudah* ('התם נמי מרבין לכבוד השבת בשמחה ובסעודה'). R' Algazi extended this to Purim too, for Purim is a day where it is customary to add rejoicing and festivities.

However, the Knesses Hagedolah (EH 62:24) disagreed with this ruling, citing the prevalent custom to require *panim chadashos* even on Purim.

Many have questioned the *psak* of R' Algazi - the parallel he draws from Shabbos seems flawed, because the *seudah* of Purim does not require bread according to many (eg Magen Avraham 695:9), and therefore would be like *seudas shelishis* on Shabbos which does not have the same dispensation (see Beis Yosef EH 62). Even according to the authorities who do require bread at the Purim *seudah*, many still question the parallel, saying that since Purim is not a Yom Tov, it would be [like *chol hamoed*](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/25776/panim-chadashos-on-chol-hamoed?rq=1) and require *panim chadashos*.

As quoted in @chatzkel's answer, Beer Heitiv (OC 696:12 and EH 64:10) quotes Knesses Hagedolah as being unsure.

Later authorities ([R' Shimon Sofer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shimon_Sofer_(Hungarian_rabbi)), *Hisoirerus Beteshuva* V4, EH 29:2; R' Betzalel Stern [*Betzel Chochmah*](https://hebrewbooks.org/1808) V2 Siman 1) rule not to recite *sheva brachos* without *panim chadashos*. This is the ruling of R' Shmuel Kaminetsky shlit"a (Kovetz Halachos, Purim 16:14), and R' Ovadia Yosef (Yabia Omer Vol 8, Siman 23:17).

Answer (score 4):

The Be’er Heitiv [EH 64:10](https://www.sefaria.org/Ba%27er_Hetev_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Even_HaEzer.62.8?lang=bi) says it’s a safek